# Wrong view showing on posting in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to submit a form to Joomla. My action URL is

```
index.php?option=com_hello&controller=createTask
```

it works fine.

But when i use `action=index.php` and `contorller` and `option` are my `POST` variable then this statement

```
$viewName     = $app->input->getWord('view', 'createTask');
```

outputs `view='featured'` though view is none of my `POST` variable.

Where is that view coming from?

Comment: check your view.html.php if non of value is define for view variable it may tooks 'featured'. Also explicitly passing controller you can use like task=controller_name.task_name

Comment: What method in the createtask.php controller are you using to test the view variable? display() ? There is no task in your request. Anyhow, given the issue (view being overridden only with POST but not with GET) in the above method you should have code that performs the assignment. How does the behaviour change if you POST the view value as well?

Comment: How does the behaviour change if you POST the view value as well? that's what I want to know. i am using getWord() to retrieve controller name. then instantiate that controller. after that the default task i.e. execute() is being used in my component only. one more thing my component is using lendr JOOMLA extension as a reference.. . . .

Comment: if view is used as separate hidden variable every thing works perfectly fine. . . but when I delete that hidden input statement then "featured" is received as view name. where as nothing named featured is being defined as a view.